# YouTube Data v3 API not returning all uploaded video IDs using playlistIistItems.list method with upload playlist ID

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm attempting to pull the complete set of uploaded videos for a given YouTube channel using the YouTube Data v3 API (more specifically, using the Python client). I'm following the steps outlined in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjUlmco7v2M) Google tutorial. I'm also using authenticated requests.

When I follow this process, I've noticed that for some YouTube channels, not all video IDs are returned from the playlistItems.list method (when compared to the full list of videos available in YouTube Studio).

I've analysed the missing videos and can't see any reason why they would be omitted - they're publicly available and aren't restricted to a certain region/age group. I'm also correctly paginating through the responses.

Another strange observation is that when I request the information related to one of these missing videos using the videos.list method, the API returns the relevant data. So there seems to be some discrepancy between the data that feeds the playlistItems.list method and the videos.list method.

Has anyone observed something similar? If so, are there any workarounds? Or is it a known bug/limitation with the YouTube Data v3 API?

**UPDATE**

I've noticed that when I make an non-authenticated request, the video IDs returned includes the missing video IDs. However, I need to make authenticated requests, as I'm looking to pull non-public videos.

Here's an example of the code I'm running (essentially a modified version of the YouTube API docs example provided [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix=true)):

```py
import os

import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]
api_key = "MY_API_KEY" # Needs setting to your API key
channel_playlist_id = "MY_CHANNEL_PLAYLIST_ID" # Needs setting to a channel playlist ID
client_secrets_file = "PATH_TO_MY_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON" # Needs setting to path to channel's client secrets JSON

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"    
    credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(client_secrets_file)
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, 
        api_version, 
        credentials=credentials, # Keep if authenticated request, remove if not 
        developerKey=api_key
    )
    items = []
    request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        part='contentDetails',
        playlistId=channel_playlist_id
    )
    while True:
        response = request.execute()
        items.extend(response['items'])
        if 'nextPageToken' in response:
            request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
                part='contentDetails',
                playlistId=channel_playlist_id,
                pageToken=response['nextPageToken']
        )
        else:
            break
    video_ids = [i['contentDetails']['videoId'] for i in items]
    return video_ids

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_ids = main()
```

Comment: May you provide such a video id missing?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison one such video ID is TrKUoZXLapY

Comment: As [this code snippet](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/3643779) shows, I do not notice any issue.

Comment: Thanks for checking - can you try using the Python client? That's where I'm seeing the issue.

Comment: I will not verify with the Python client sorry. For others to check what you are stating provide such a Python client checking code.

Comment: I will put together an example code snippet. However I have done some more digging and noticed that when I use an *unauthenticated* request, the response contains the missing video IDs. The problem is that I want to use authenticated requests so I can pull non-public videos. I guess a workaround would be to call the API twice (once using an authenticated request, then again using an unauthenticated request), then create a set of video IDs from the two responses, but it'll effectively double the number of calls made to the API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256718/discussion-between-james-laidler-and-benjamin-loison).